# Два вида абзацев: с отступом и без отступа

Tags: пунктуация, оформление-текста, абзац

```
   "Всем известно, что абзац - это часть текста, выделяемая отступом сверху и с начала текста (красная строка)", - это предложение и есть пример.

   "Но существуют ли вообще последовательно идущие предложения текста, в которых следующее предложение начинается с новой КРАСНОЙ строки, но при этом не выделяется отступом вниз", - вот как в этом примере тоже.

   Вопрос очень важный, поскольку часто выделять части текста абзацем в классическом его понимании с отступом вниз не очень удобно. Текст словно растягивается. Тогда как чередовать по смыслу части текста с отступом вниз и без отступа очень даже удобно.
```

Возможно ли использование этих двух типов абзацев текста вместе?

Comment: «Вот как в этом примере тоже:-)» Где он, этот пример:-)? И ещё: правильнее было бы перейти на «классическую» терминологию. Отступ — не междустрочный интервал.

Answer (score 2):

Денис, Вы спрашиваете не о русском языке, а о полиграфическом дизайне, что всегда остаётся вопросом вкуса издателя.

Вот я полиграфист — и институт полиграфический за плечами, и двадцатилетний опыт работы в типографии.

Такое вот —

> Но существуют ли вообще последовательно идущие предложения текста, в
> которых следующее предложение начинается с новой КРАСНОЙ строки, но
> при этом не выделяется отступом вниз —

полиграфистам не понять ("выделение отступом вниз").

Исходя из нынешнего опыта, могу подсказать, что однажды встреченное отклонение от нормы будет воспринято как ошибка. Если же оно (отклонение) будет регулярно наличествовать, то справедливо будет воспринято как дизайнерский ход.

Другой вопрос — смотрится / не смотрится, но это дело хозяйское.